# Trim whitespace inside tags?

Tags: xmllint

I'm using xmllint to re-format some xml. I notice it seems to leave enclosed text alone. For example, this

```
<tag>
<p>
<i>
test
</i>
</p>
</tag>
```

becomes this

```
<tag>
    <p>
        <i>
test
</i>
    </p>
</tag>
```

Is there a way to force it to put the text right after the opening tag and follow that immediately with the closing tag? Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
<tag>
    <p>
        <i>test</i>
    </p>
</tag>
```

I suppose that amounts to having it ignore leading and trailing whitespace inside tags. I can do it with some preprocessing via regex, but is there any native way?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `tidy` for this:

```
echo '<tag>
<p>
<i>
test
</i>
</p>
</tag>' |    tidy -xml -iq
```

Output:

```
<tag>
  <p>
    <i>test</i>
  </p>
</tag>
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally `--noblanks` will strip ignorable/insignificant whitespace, but in this case xmllint sees the whitespace as significant and won't ignore it.

In addition to the suggestion of "tidy" in another answer, you could also [use xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html) to normalize the whitespace of all text nodes...

**Command line**

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//text()" -x "normalize-space()" input.xml
```

**Output**

```xml
<tag>
  <p>
    <i>test</i>
  </p>
</tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u //*[not(*)] -x normalize-space(.) file.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tag>
  <p>
    <i>test</i>
  </p>
</tag>
```